# VBA insert variable formula with counting

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to for the number of sheets in a workbook insert formulas into `columns C & D`, I am happy producing a list of the available sheets and have a formula;

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&$A$1:$A$10&"'!"&"$BI$1:$BI$1000"),C4,INDIRECT("'"&$A$1:$A$10&"'!"&"$ax$1:$ax$1000")))
```

which does the processing. I wish to change `$A$10` to the number of sheets, which are listed in column a already coded. so `$A & "variable"`. additionally is it possible to insert into the same number of rows are variable, i.e. insert the formula in `C2:D4` if there are 3 sheets in the workbook etc.

very new to VBA so any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Yes you can do that. You might wanna have a look at `Range.FormulaR1C1` function. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.formular1c1)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't quite understand your formula but I think that you want formulae in the same number of rows as there are sheets. You can try this code:

```
Public Sub InsertFormulae() 'Sample Name
    Dim inCount As Integer      'To move through rows
    inCount = 2
    ActiveSheet.Range("C2:D" & Rows.Count).ClearContents  'To reset C and D columns
    For Each Worksheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets       'To cycle through all sheets
        ActiveSheet.Range("C" & inCount).Formula = ""     'Insert Formula for C Column instead of ""
        ActiveSheet.Range("D" & inCount).Formula = ""     'Insert Formula for D Column instead of ""
        inCount = inCount + 1
    Next Worksheet
End Sub
```

This will satisfy your criteria that if you have 3 sheets, formulae will be put in C2:D4.